# Do satellites need to have their orbits externally maintained?

Tags: satellites

Is the speed of a satellite self maintained ? Or it needs anything to be done externally ?

Condition : The satellite is in the orbit where it is held in equilibrium by the force of gravity and its centrifugal force.

Comment: Are you asking if there is anything slowing down a satellite, e.g. friction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the typical orbital life of an artificial satellite?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30709/)

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks for the message. So we dont have to supply an external energy ??

Comment: @ACuriousMind No. I dont consider friction or air drag. in the ideal case, Do we have to supply energy to keep the satellite revolve with the same velocity ?

Comment: Any satellite in a low orbit experiences atmospheric drag and therefore does need regular orbital corrections. For example the International Space Station [needs to fire its boosters regularly to stop its orbit from decaying](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/does-the-orbit-of-the-iss-decay). If the satellite is far enough away that atmospheric drag is negligable then it will orbit forever (though its orbit will be perturbed by inhomogeneities in the Earth's gravitational field).

Answer (score 1):

All that is needed is gravity. There is absolutely no need to invoke the centrifugal force to explain an orbit. This argument doesn't even make sense because when it is used, the satellite is shown as moving.

A nice simple way to look at orbits is via Newton's cannon. Imagine a cannon atop the only mountain on an airless and, except for this one mountain, spherical planet. Fire the cannon and the cannonball will fly a bit before falling to the surface of the planet. Add a bit more gunpowder and the cannon will fly a bit further. Add even more and now the cannonball flies partly around the curved surface of the planet before finally hitting the surface. Eventually you'll have the cannonball flying halfway around the planet before it hits. What happens if you add a bit more gunpowder? The cannonball is now in orbit. It will eventually come all the way around the planet and hit the cannon from behind.

That said, there are lots of things that perturb a satellite's orbit. Satellites in low Earth orbit fly through the Earth's upper atmosphere. This eventually slows the satellite down to the point where it enters the thicker part of the atmosphere and burns up. To counter this, satellites in low Earth orbit occasionally need to boost themselves back up to a higher altitude.

Other perturbations include the non-spherical shape of the Earth, gravitational perturbations from the Moon and the Sun (and Jupiter and Venus and ...), solar radiation pressure, general relativity, and others. While the satellite might still be in orbit, these perturbations tend to move a satellite from the orbit it is supposed to be in to some other orbit. As is the case for satellites in low Earth orbit, other satellites occasionally need to boost themselves to bring themselves back to the desired orbit.

Comment: If so, wont we able to make a satellite revolve at any orbit irrespective of its speed ?

Comment: For a given altitude, there's but one speed that results in a circular orbit. Orbits moving slower than this speed will have a perihelion (closest distance) that is less than the current altitude. The orbit won't last forever if the perihelion distance is inside the Earth's atmosphere The flip side of this is escape velocity (which would be better called "escape speed"). A vehicle moving faster than escape velocity is on a hyperbolic trajectory rather than an orbit.

Comment: Here i am concerned of circular orbits