# How long can a satellite stay in orbit?

Tags: satellites

Well, obviously billions of years if it is the moon. Or not very long if it is only 100km above the Earth, due to atmospheric drag. Also, how long it stays up would depend on density ie how much energy it has to dissipate in order to lose speed to drag due to mass/cross sectional area.

However, somewhere in the middle we have satellites that will stay up for... how long? How long will geo-sync satellites remain in orbit? What forces are exerted on them that will affect their stay eg magnetic field effects, solar wind etc? If we wanted to put a satellite in orbit and keep it there (say) 10,000 years how close could we get to Earth before this became unrealistic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the typical orbital life of an artificial satellite?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30709/)

Comment: Related to it, but the real underlying question is about satellite lifetimes at different altitudes. Also are geosync satellites really "for ever" as stated? I doubt it.